# Dart analysis often freeze on android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-studio-4.1, dart-analyzer

Dart analysis often freeze on android studio. So, quick doc and code completion didn't work.

I have tried to restart android studio, delete file on folder .dartServer, downgrade dart plugin and flutter plugin version, downgrade flutter sdk, disable un-used plugins, increase memory of android studio, and reinstall android studio. In vscode, dart analysis often freeze too.

My laptop storage is ssd, still has empty space 110 gb, and ram 16 gb.

Size of lib folder on project : 215 KB (613 KB on disk).

Please, can anybody tell me the solution?

Comment: have you tried it with other projects or used flutter clean?

Comment: yes, i did. In new project, there is no problem.But, I think this problem appear, because the files is bigger

Comment: and did you maybe try to create a new project and only transfer your code? then you would see if that is really the problem or if it is a misconfigured project etc.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, and the problem still appear

Comment: this helped me,  [Enable Scope Analysis to the Current Package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223418/13521429)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [link](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2865)

as suggested try to enable dart.previewLsp

In VSCode settings, go to settings search for "dart preview lsp", select the checkbox under Dart: Preview Lsp and restart.

[image]

Unfortunately, Dart preview [LSP](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/tools/) is not supported for android studio yet.

Comment: I just followed the link. Does dart.previewLsp settings only available in vscode? how about in android studio?

Comment: I mean, how to settings dart.previewLsp in android studio?

Comment: Android studio is not yet supported, check the following link: https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/tools/ , for supported editors.