# How to change Android Studio Quick Fixes default suggesstion?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, syntax-error, lint

In Android Studio when there is an error, and you hover over it, the Android studio shows the lint error and suggests `Quick fixes`.

In flutter development when a class is not imported, the quick fix suggests to import the class.
[image: Import suggestion]

The default suggestion is to import the class in **relative** path.

If you click 'More actions' you can see the option to import in **absolute** path as the second option.
[image: The whole list of suggestions]

What I want is to the make **2nd** `Quick Fix` suggestion, the **absolute** import option, as the **default (1st)** suggestion? How can I do that? In short I want to reorder the Quick Fix suggestion.

I know the error is shown by the `dart lint` and i suppose the quick action is also suggested by the `dart lint`. So can I configure the suggestions anyhow?

Comment: For me I solved the problem with this solition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217842/android-studio-errors-in-dart-are-not-showing-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discomfort. I couldn't find an actual solution but using short cut(Quick fix) is a lot better for me. Plz check below.

#### To summon this magical feature, simply use the key combination of ⌥ + Enter on MacOSX and Alt + Enter on Windows/Linux:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/2807578-android-studio-tips-and-tricks#toc-anchor-014

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about the keyboard shortcut, but what i want is to make the 2nd suggestion, default in the quick fix list.