# Errors not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio is not showing syntax or code errors.
I have 2 projects, on one of them everything works just fine and on the other I don't get the red warnings. Even if I write some non sense no warnings is shown. It is not the Power save mode. I have tried that already.

Comment: I found the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217842/android-studio-errors-in-dart-are-not-showing-on-the-screen)